# Can a PowerShell script run multiple long-running commands while still displaying the output?

Tags: powershell, background, console, stdout, scp

I have an scp command that I want to run repeatedly and also watch the output.  Putting one or multiple scp commands in a script allows me to see the output but each has to finish before moving on to the next.  I can open multiple PowerShell windows but I want to scale it up past the point where that is practical.

I've played with start-job and that allows me to run multiples but when using get-job/receive-job/wait-job I haven't been able to get what I want.  I've also tried invoke-command and invoke-expression.

My command is something like this:

> C:\temp\scp.exe' -i c:\temp\key  c:\temp\test100.dat user1`@10.10.0.100:/tmp/

The output is updated regularly (once/second I guess) and looks like this:

> Transfering c:\temp\test100.dat
>   c:\temp\test100.dat                      | 5.55mB | 812.13kB/s | 00:01:59 | 5%

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Can you describe exactly what it is you're wanting to get that background jobs aren't providing?

Comment: @mjolinor - I want to view the output from the command as it is happening.

Comment: Would a 1-2 second refresh rate (you seem to have that now) be acceptable or is it critical that you see everything real-time.

Comment: @mjolinor - 1-2 second refresh is OK.

Comment: That seems like it ought to be do-able.  You should be able to cycle through receive-job, format and write the job status for all the running jobs within a couple of seconds, and have a near-realtime display of the output of several jobs on one console.

Comment: I'm with @mjolinor.  This should be doable however I'm not sure why you're using Wait-Job since it normally blocks.  Just sit in a loop that say sleeps for 500 ms to 1 sec so you don't chew up too much CPU and does a receive-job on any job that HasMoreData. The jobs will dump output to their output stream while processing - not just when they're done.  When you exec Receive-Job it will grab the output that is available.  Call Receive-Job again and it will grab any new output since the last call.

Comment: Hmm.  Thanks for the feedback.  I'll work harder at seeing if I can get Receive-Job to provide what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pipe the output to file with Out-File and monitor the file with http://www.baremetalsoft.com/wintail/